# Using if-condition to check filename

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm doing a real silly mistake in Python but unable to find what it is

I'm doing something like this in python

```
filename="file1"
if name == 'file1'
    print 1
```

I'm getting an invalid syntax error

Comment: What Python tutorial are you using?  What tools (IDE) are you using?  How are you preparing this code?  Are you using IDLE?  Are you using Notepad?  How are you getting this error?  What is the **Exact** error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is name?? did you define it elsewhere?? I assume its "filename" instead, so

```
filename="file1"
if filename == 'file1':
    print 1
```

if "name" is defined, then the problem is indeed the ":" at the end of "if" line.

Comment: while `name` is not defined, it wouldn't cause the `SyntaxError`. `SyntaxError` is generated on compilation time and completely independent of the `NameError`.

Comment: i see. I didn't see the last part that describes the error he's got. thanks

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a colon

```
filename="file1"
if name == 'file1':
    print 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put a colon at the end of the if statment

```
filename="file1"
if name == 'file1':
    print 1
```